# Keep the password permanently on BIOS

Tags: bios, operating-systems, password-protection

Is there any mechanism or tweak to keep the passwords permanently for BIOS?

If I remove the CMOS battery for a while, the password gets reset. How can I prevent this?

Comment: anything you would add to secure it can be removed (nearly) as easily as the CMOS battery unless it is soldered onto the motherboard. also note this reset functionality is a usability feature to avoid users locking themselves out and bricking the board

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can't. When you remove the CMOS battery, the chip which stores the password (and other BIOS configuration) loses power and eventually forgets the stored configuration.

If you want to password-protect the BIOS and avoid people removing the CMOS battery to reset it, you should look into physical security for the computer case.